# Combine two tables with type attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want two combine two tables in a query where the resulting table has an extra type column to specify which table the value was taken from:

**table1**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |

**table2**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | name3 |
| 4 | name4 |

**result**

| table | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | 1 | name1 |
| table1 | 2 | name2 |
| table2 | 3 | name3 |
| table2 | 4 | name4 |

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a union query:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS [table], id, name FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2', id, name FROM table2
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the union query is a quick solution. If you don't want any duplicate, simply use `UNION`, without `ALL`.